Show that every element of $F$ is an eigenvalue of $S.$
Here is the question I am trying to solve:
Define the backward shift operator $S \in \mathcal{L}(F^{\infty})$ by $$S(z_1, z_2, \dots) = (z_2, z_3, \dots ).$$
$(a)$ Show that every element of $F$ is an eigenvalue of $S.$
$(b)$ Find all eigenvectors of $S.$
My questions are:
1-What is $F$ in my case here? I am using Linear Algebra Done right fourth edition - Chapter five section A.
I think $F$ here is the field whether the complex or the real one.
2- How can I prove $(a)$ and $(b)$?'
Any hints will be greatly appreciated!
My thoughts are:
$(a) $Am I going to take sequence of $\lambda$'s and just apply $S$ to it?i.e., $$S((\lambda, \lambda, \dots)) = (\lambda, \lambda, \dots )$$
But how does this shows that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $S$ with respect to the eigenvector $(\lambda, \lambda, \dots ).$ Could anyone clarify to me please?
$(b)$ according to the hint of copper.hat given in the comments below I would have $$z_2 = \lambda z_1,$$ $$z_3 = \lambda^2 z_1,$$ $$z_4 = \lambda^3 z_1,$$  and so on.
Edit:
I found a detailed answer to part (b) here Eigenvalues and eigenvectors computation (in infinite dimension)
My question now is for part (a) only and it is:
what about all the eigenvalues what are they? Is every scalar in the field $F$ is an eigenvalue? If so, why?
Here is the solution I found for part (b) online:
Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.
Then
$$
\lambda(z_1, z_2, z_3, \dots) = (z_2, z_3, \dots),
$$
If $\lambda = 0$, we have $0 = z_2 = z_3 = ...$, and so $\lambda = 0$, $(1, 0, 0,...)$ is an eigenvalue and a corresponding eigenvector.
Suppose $\lambda \neq 0$, which implies that $z_k = \frac{1}{\lambda} z_{k+1}$.
But $z_{k+1} = \frac{1}{\lambda} z_{k+2}$.
It is easy to see (and easily proven by induction) that $z_k = (\frac{1}{\lambda})^{n-k} z_n$ or $z_n = \lambda^{n-k} z_k$.
Choose $k = 1$, and we have a formula for any geometric sequence.
Hence, all real numbers are eigenvalues of $T$ and any of their respective geometric sequences are the corresponding eigenvectors.
But I am not getting at all this sentence in the solution:
"we have a formula for any geometric sequence.
Hence, all real numbers are eigenvalues of $T$ ", could anyone explain this to me please? This is the only part I do not understand now and of course the sentence following this sentence in the solution I also do not understand.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Unfortunately, the most relevant comment was deleted.

Unfortunately the relevant comment was removed from the answer.
The answer really does boil down to solving $Sz = \lambda z$ and by direct computation we see that $Sz = \lambda z$ iff $z_{k+1} = \lambda z_k$, with $z_1$ arbitrary.
For (a), pick $z_1=1$ and any $\lambda$. Then $z=(1,\lambda,\lambda^2,..)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$.
For (b), we see that $z$ is an eigenvector iff there is some $\lambda$ and $z_1 \neq 0$ such that $z=(z_1, \lambda z_1,\lambda^2 z_1,...)$.
That's it.

Does what you said in $(a)$ shows that any $\lambda in F$ is an eigenvalue of the backward shift operator? If so, why this proves this?

So, there is nothing about geometric progression at all in the solution?

@Intuition You need to review what is meant by eigenvalue and geometric progression. $(1,\lambda, \lambda^2,...)$ is a geometric progression. What happens when you apply $S$ to this? Note that $(\lambda, \lambda^2,...) = \lambda (1,\lambda, \lambda^2,...)$.
